# Mesh composed of duplicated objects created with multiple array modifiers won't scale

Tags: modeling

I'm fairly new to blender and I'm having an issue with a scene I built. It's basically a cylindrical building composed of six floors (the external structure is hidden in the attached gif). There are petal shaped windows which encircle each floor, and each window has a decorative sash on top of it. I modeled a single window, then used the array modifier to generate one circular floor of windows, and then I added a second array modifier to create the other five floors. I did the same for the sashes.

I need to scale the building as a single unit, and everything is behaving as expected except for the mesh containing the sashes. I select all the meshes together, click 's', and everything scales correctly but the mesh layer containing the sashes doesn't react at all. Hopefully this issue is illustrated by the attached gif where I've hidden everything except the windows and sashes. You can see when I drag the mouse the windows scale normally; the sashes don't scale at all.

I've tried taking the sash mesh and applying all the modifiers and then applying all transforms, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The origin seems to be set correctly. Still, whenever I grab everything and try to scale it as a group the sashes get left behind. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what the problem could be?

Thank you in advance for any insight you might be able to offer.

Edit: project file available here-
https://blend-exchange.com/b/DG4n8ARj/

[image: Clicking 's' to scale works on one mesh, but not the other]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: The issue is illustrated by the GIF, but unfortunately nothing else but the issue. No settings etc., just from viewing it I guess most likely the problem is shown in Josh's answer below - if this does not solve it, we probably need your file as Rick suggested.

Comment: Apologies- I posted a stripped down version of the file. I have the collapsed meshes in there, and I also copied a set that have the modifiers on them. There's also a lattice warping them slightly, so I left that in as well-- :[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DG4n8ARj" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DG4n8ARj/)

Comment: @Weirzbowski As Josh has answered, you've locked the Scale of the object

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the object has its scale locked?

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks! Kind of a humbling whiff there. I'm feeling my way around the UI and when I saw the lock icons my brain just assumed they were there to lock those axis together, not scaling entirely. Dumb assumption on my part. I appreciate the correction!